# TFS GIT - Source Settings for build definition tick box missing

Tags: git, tfs

We have a project in TFS which uses GIT.

There is a build definition setup and under 'Edit Build Definition' | 'Source Settings', I can see the option 'Get sources from a Team Foundation Git repository'.

I've cloned the build definition (Right click | Clone build definition). I select 'Edit Build Definition' on the cloned build and under 'Source Settings' there is no 'Get sources from a Team Foundation Git repository' tick box. Instead I can see 'working folders' with 'Status', 'Source Control Folder' and 'Build Agent folder'.

Any idea why I cant select the git source settings?

All the other settings are identical minus the name.

Comment: Same problem here - after cloning the build definition the Source Settings view is screwed up/missing the git specific settings.

Answer (score 1):

I've just run into this issue.

'Clone build definition' is a feature from the Productivity Power Tools extension and therein lies the problem.
You need to install the Community Build Manager extension and clone with that:

[VS2012](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/cfdb84b4-285e-4eeb-9fa9-dad9bfe2cd10)
[VS2013](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/73bf2d8e-aec6-406c-8e7f-1c678e46557f)

Once installed go to 'Tools > Community TFS Build Manager' to view the existing definitions. You can clone from there. Cloning 'To Project' seems to be akin to the Power Tools clone feature.

Note: I uninstalled Power Tools before installing CBM for 2013 but I don't know if this is necessary.